# getDesiredMinimumHeight/Width() in 'Wallapper manager'

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

i looked at these 2 function in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getDesiredMinimumHeight())

i want to get the desired wallaper dimensions,
running those functions on an SGS3 (1280x720) with stock launcher,
i got both minDesiredWidth + minDesiredHight: 1280x1280

same thing with a Note 3 (1920x1080) i got 1920x1920

i want to know the desired ratio of wallpaper the device wants, and i thought i would get it from those 2 functions.

both those devices stock launchers have a static background image of their respective screen resolutions, so why does getDesiredMinimumWidth doesn't give me 1280/1080 for each device respectively?

how do i know the proper ratio for the device?

Comment: what is your actual goal?

Comment: knowing the proper image ratio to be used as the device's wallpaper

Comment: I have the same issue with Galaxy S8+, it should have returned 2880x2960 but it returns 2960x2960 for some reason. Could it be an issue with Samsung phones ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended result of the methods, the code used in the WallpaperManager class is:

```java
return sGlobals.mService.getHeightHint();
```

and

```java
return sGlobals.mService.getWidthHint();
```

It isn't mentioned anywhere why they return the same value, but to get the true values of WxH, you should use:

```java
Point displaySize = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(displaySize);
```

and refer to the values with `int width = displaySize.x` and `int height = displaySize.y`